# UIScrollView has ambiguous scrollable content but it has no content

Tags: uiscrollview, autolayout

Why does this scroll view have ambiguous scrollable content, when it doesn't have any content?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you are laying this out with the intention of adding subviews (with proper constraints) to the scroll view at run-time.

But, Storyboard / Interface Builder has no idea what your code is going to do in the future.

You can either leave it as is and ignore the warning,

or

Tell Storyboard to stop warning you about it by selecting the scroll view and then selecting `Ambiguity: Never Verify` in the size inspector pane:

[image]

or

Add some content, such as a `UIView` that you will use to hold the UI elements you plan to add at run-time.